# How to remove first " from string

Tags: java, json

I am getting this string from server I need to remove first and last "

getting this

> {"TestServiceResult":"[{\"screen_refresh_interval\":4,\"station_list_last_update\":\"update4\"},{\"screen_refresh_interval\":4,\"station_list_last_update\":\"update4\"},{\"screen_refresh_interval\":4,\"station_list_last_update\":\"update4\"},{\"screen_refresh_interval\":4,\"station_list_last_update\":\"update4\"},{\"screen_refresh_interval\":4,\"station_list_last_update\":\"update4\"}]"}

output

> {"TestServiceResult":[{\"screen_refresh_interval\":4,\"station_list_last_update\":\"update4\"},{\"screen_refresh_interval\":4,\"station_list_last_update\":\"update4\"},{\"screen_refresh_interval\":4,\"station_list_last_update\":\"update4\"},{\"screen_refresh_interval\":4,\"station_list_last_update\":\"update4\"},{\"screen_refresh_interval\":4,\"station_list_last_update\":\"update4\"}]}

```
int index =test.indexOf('[');           
int index2 =test.indexOf(']');
```

Comment: You forgot to post your attempts.

Comment: nt index =test.indexOf('[');
   
   int index2 =test.indexOf(']');

Comment: @Ian Roberts is right.this is json response so you have to parse no eliminate first and last is proper way.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to remove first and last "

No you don't.  What you have there is a JSON object containing one property named `TestServiceResult` whose value is a string that itself happens to be valid JSON.  What you actually need to do is extract that string and pass it back to the JSON parser so you get out an array, then create a new JSON object with a property `TestServiceResult` whose value is that array, and serialize this new object back to another string.

Simply stripping the first and last quote marks won't be sufficient because that will leave the other quotes still escaped as `\"` which isn't valid.

Comment: @user944513 there are a number of different JSON libraries available for Java, my personal favourite is [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Comment: is it support blackberry ?

Comment: I download and add in lib folder what next

Comment: @user944513 ... read the library's documentation?  If you get stuck and have a specific problem using it then feel free to ask a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String removeCharAt(String s, int pos) {
 StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer( s.length() - 1 );
 buffer.append( s.substring(0,pos) ).append( s.substring(pos+1) );
 return buffer.toString();
}
```

You can even change this code a little bit to work with 2 parameters, to avoid calling this method twice.

Comment: You can use StringBuffer#deleteCharAt :)

Comment: Ah, I guess the code behind it is the same, but thanks for pointing it out :D

Comment: More or less. Both methods(append vs deleteCharAt) are using System.arraycopy internally, so I believe deleteCharAt may be faster due to 1 call(deleteCharAt) vs 2 calls(append).

Answer (score 0):

Use `string substring()` function,

```
    String test = ".... my Data ";
    int index =test.indexOf('[') + 1 ; //+1 to leave the character '[' as not needed           
    int index2 =test.indexOf(']') -1; ////-1 to leave the character ']' as not needed         
    String output = test .substring(index,index2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the structure of the JSON is not going to change you can probably use the below also.

```
str = str.replace("\"[{", "[{");
str = str.replace("]\"}", "]}");
```